# Generators of 3/2 isospin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin

The generators of 3/2 isospin look like this:

\begin{align}
    T^1=\frac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
0 & 0 &\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&0
\end{pmatrix} \qquad 
    T^2=\frac{2i}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &0& -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
0 &0&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&0
\end{pmatrix}\qquad 
    T^3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &- \frac{1}{3}&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

The elements of these matrices appear in the Lagrangian for the pion nucleon delta vertex:
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}_{\pi N \Delta}=i \frac{h_A}{2f_\pi m_\Delta} (\partial_\nu \bar{\Delta}_\alpha) \gamma^{\mu\nu\alpha} T_a^\dagger N (\partial_\mu \pi_a) + i \frac{h_A}{2 f_\pi m_\Delta} \bar N  \gamma^{\mu\nu\alpha} T_a (\partial_\nu \Delta_\alpha) (\partial_\mu \pi_a) 
\end{align}

How do I know which element $T_a$ I have to use for which vertex depending on the involved particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the real source of your confusion is the missing $P_{1/2}$ projector next to you nucleon spinor, that is, your writing your nucleon isodoublet as an isoquartet, so as to contract it with the Δ isoquartet!
$$
N \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0\\p\\n\\0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This wink-and-grin way, you are contracting isospin 3/2 generators between apparent isoquartets...

I gather you have repeated may times this rewriting of pion gradients, in the adjoint rep of isospin, in the doublet representation, but, of course, it is *identical* in the quartet representation you are looking at,
$$
\partial_\mu \pi^a T^a=  \partial_\mu \pi^0 T^3 +\sqrt{2} \partial_\mu \pi^+ T^- +\sqrt{2}\partial_\mu \pi^- T^+,
$$
with
$$
 T^+=\frac{2}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where I've possibly been cavalier with the normalizations of the respective states. The important think for you is to recognize charge conservation here.

So the rest is being careful in doing the contraction and recognizing the answer in your peculiar writing of the [Rarita-Schwinger operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation), so for example, your second isospin invariant term is proportional to
$$
 \overline{ N}  \gamma^5 \gamma_{\rho} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\kappa\rho} (\partial_\mu \pi_a)T^a (\partial_\nu \Delta_\kappa) \\  = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\bar p\\\bar n\\0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \gamma^5 \gamma_{\rho} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\kappa\rho} 
\Bigl (\partial_\mu \pi^0 T^3 +\sqrt{2}\partial_\mu \pi^+ T^- +\sqrt{2}\partial_\mu \pi^- T^+  \Bigr) \begin{pmatrix}\Delta^{++}\\\Delta^{+}\\\Delta^{0}\\\Delta^{-}\end{pmatrix}_\kappa ~~. 
$$

Plug in your matrices and read off the respective couplings.